# How to edit local JSON file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Please answer me as example `Select` code

1. I want to add values into array local file JSON (insert member to JSON)
2. element is also replaced my element like `type`, `name`... in JSON (update member in JSON)
3. delete number line where `id="1"` and `email="amir@site.com"` (delete memebr in JSON)

JSON file : `report.json`

```
var amir='{"reports":[' +
    '{"id": "1","type": "admin","name": "amir","email": "amir@site.com","password": "123"},' +
    '{"id": "2","type": "member","name": "kevin","email": "ad@ad.com","password": "1234"}]}';
```

example `select` code for check register admin :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(amir);
for(c = 0; c <= obj.reports.length - 1; c++) {
    type = obj.reports[c].type.toString();
    if (type == "admin") {
        active = 1;
    }

    if (c == obj.reports.length - 1) {
        if (active == 1)
            alert("Yes");
        else
            alert("No");
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you include json file in your code? what's the include method?

Comment: Javascript in the browser does not have the privileges to edit files on disk.

Comment: That's right. I think you should write php file for manipulating you json. (Use json_decode, json_encode functions.) Than speak with it by your javascript (ajax-post, ajax-get etc)

Comment: Or use a database. Anyway you have to have a php-interface for making changes.

Comment: `@user1011278` with syntax code in html : `<script src="javascript/report.json"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as saving the result of manipulated JSON to the disk, that has to be done on the back end, or you can open a window with the file as content, setting the MIME type to json, which could prompt the user to save it to their computer, depending on their browser settings.  See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_open.asp.

See below for manipulation of JSON object.

```js
var amir='{"reports":[' +
    '{"id": "1","type": "admin","name": "amir","email": "amir@site.com","password": "123"},' +
    '{"id": "2","type": "member","name": "kevin","email": "ad@ad.com","password": "1234"}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(amir);

document.getElementById("before").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log("Before", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))); // objects use pointers, clone it to see the value at this point


// Add a new member into the array (example, using made up values)
obj.reports.push({
  "id": ""+obj.reports.length + 1,
  "type": "member",
  "name": "Joe",
  "email": "asdf@gmail.com",
  "password": "ajdj12oi42"
});

document.getElementById("during").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log("During", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))); // objects use pointers, clone it to see the value at this point

// When deleting items, it is often easier to start high, and end low
for(var c = obj.reports.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
  // Delete member in JSON where id == 1 and email == amir@site.com
  if(obj.reports[c].id == "1" && obj.reports[c].email == "amir@site.com") {
    obj.reports.splice(c, 1);
  } else {
    // Add values into the objects (example, using random numbers)
    obj.reports[c].newKey = "New Value! " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  }
}

document.getElementById("after").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log("After", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))); // objects use pointers, clone it to see the value at this point
```

```html
<h1>Before</h1>
<div id="before"></div>

<h1>During</h1>
<div id="during"></div>

<h1>After</h1>
<div id="after"></div>
```