# How to manipulate local JSON file using JavaScript on the client side?

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

### Context

A feature that I would like to implement is to add a local(client side) database as offline feature for my `cordova` app using basic html, css, and js. It would be a fallback in case the internet connection is cut off. What I thought was that it would store the request `url` and request data inside a local JSON file and would have an option later on to be able to resend those failed request if the internet connection is restored.

### Question

**Is there a method to manipulate (add/create, edit/update, and delete) a JSON file stored inside a client app using pure JS?**

What I've done so far is import and read a JSON file inside my app folder using the following code:

```js
fetch("./database.json")
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

*(if there's a better way to do it, feel free to give a feedback in the comments)*

That works fine and all, but  I can't find any method on how to add/edit/delete an object and save the changes to that same JSON file.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651997/how-to-edit-local-json-file-with-javascript) which is half a decade ago, it is not possible without doing it in the backend.

Comment: You would presumably use the [File API](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html) which provides read/write access to files on the local device.

Comment: @meagar thanks for that! There also seems to be another plugin more useful in this offline scenario using SQLite.